# HttpClient.SendRequest exception

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httprequest

I use Xamarin.Forms and I run my application on the Android-simulator and on my mobile device

When I try to send HttpRequestMessage, my application is turned off. This happens in the SendRequest method, but sometimes I get *An error occurred while sending the request*

- I use localhost endpoint: *http://localhost:62690*
- Uri : http://localhost:62690/api/account/login

I also created a console application, tested the request there and everything works, but Android does not.

```
public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(string uri, IRequestData data, string token = "", string header = "")
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            request.AddAuthoriationHeader(token);

            var content = data.ToJson();
            request.SetContent(content, ContentTypes.Json);

            var response =  await SendRequestAsync(request);
            var result = await HandleResponseAsync<TResult>(response);

            return result;
        }

public static void SetContent(this HttpRequestMessage request,
            string content,
            ContentTypes contentType)
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent(content,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                contentType.Value());
        }

public static string Value(this ContentTypes contentType)
        {
            switch (contentType)
            {
                case ContentTypes.XxxForm:
                    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                case ContentTypes.Json:
                    return "application/json";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(contentType), contentType, null);
            }
        }

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        return await client.SendAsync(request); // Shut down on this line
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

What is it can be and why the conversion in the console to the local host is working, but with the phone and emulator error?

Comment: The "host" of the emulator will be on ip address `10.0.2.2` Review : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using `localhost` in the address?

Then you should change that to the IP address on the network of your machine. When running the test console application, you are running from the same machine your server application is running, so `localhost` is still `localhost` from that machine.

When running this from an app, the device (even emulated) will then be the `localhost` and the server application isn't running on that device or emulator. If you want to test from a device or emulator, find the IP of your development machine (or any other machine your server application is running on) and use that as the address. This address will probably look something like: `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x`.

Depending if you are on Windows or Mac, open a console window and type `ipconfig` for Windows and `ifconfig` for Mac. You should be able to get your IP address from there.